# Spark SQL: Using Window function efficiently

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Based on different criteria I have to compare the current row's timestamp with the previous row and check the difference. It is a big dataframe with more than a billion rows. Here is the problem statement:
[image]

For every combination of `errorId` and `containerId`

- if there is only one `logId` it is new error log entry
- in case of more than one refId the if timestamp difference between previous row to the current row is more than 1 minute, it is new error log entry.

Here is the implementation:

```
//Scala Sequence of the columns
List<Column> columns = Arrays.asList(rawData.col("errorId"), rawData.col("containerid"),
            rawData.col("logId"));
    Seq<Column> columnSeq = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(columns.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
//repartitioning raw data
Dataset<Row> sortedData = rawData
                         .repartition(columnSeq)
                         .sort("timestamp");
//Windowspec
WindowSpec w = Window.partitionBy(columnSeq).orderBy("timestamp");

//lag function
sortedData.withColumn("new_log_entry", functions.lag("timestamp", 60).over(w), "false");

//Write sorted data to db
```

Is it a good idea to repartition data twice? first creating `sortedData` and then `WindowSpec`.

Does this implementation look good? How would I check for `null` logIds etc?

Comment: In the example you've given, the fifth line is marked as `TRUE` even though all lines occur within the same minute. Doesn't this contradict your problem statement?

Comment: `111, a2d` has unique `logId` id2 which fulfills the first condition.

Comment: I don't understand why you sort the data before the window function, which already has the "orderBy". I think the result is same if you remove the sort operation of the raw data.

Comment: @JiayiLiao Thanks. That was one of my questions. Do you think I should `repartition` the data twice?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav No, just use the last one.